# Jquery addClass() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    $(function () {
        $('ul.vehicletypes li').click(function () {
            $('ul.vehicletypes li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

but absolute not working! The `.active` class is working if I add manualy.

The html code

```html
  

  <div class="vehicletype">
    <ul class="vehicletypes">
     <li ><a href="index.php?vehicletype=car">Car</a><li>
        <li ><a href="index.php?vehicletype=van">Van</a><li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: I'm wondering what $(this) is actually returning, is it what you expect?

Comment: Did you add Jquery library ?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

its added.

Comment: Check your jQuery library imported or not, or you can post your code on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following

```
$(function () {
});
```

is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

So I don't see any reason of why you have used it twice.

That you probably want is the following:

```
$(function () {
    // Here you attach a click handler for the click event on the
    // li elements of a ul.
    $('ul.vehicletypes li').click(function () {

        // You remove the active class
        $('ul.vehicletypes li').removeClass('active');

        // You add the active class to the currently clicked li element.
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Using it twice will not stop it from working.. `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    alert();
  });
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.vehicletypes li').click(function () {
            $('ul.vehicletypes li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **missed a semi-colon** right after the dropdown() 
Please load the jquery library

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        $(function () {
            $('ul.vehicletypes li').click(function () {
                $('ul.vehicletypes li').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    });
```

Please check this link:https://jsfiddle.net/5e29901t/10/

Comment: not working. :/ Alert is okey,but didnt add the class.. -.-"